# tmux config + bash config

Tags: tmux

I want to setup my terminal such that whenever I start it, it starts tmux in split window.

I know I want to add this into my `.tmux.config`:
`split-window -v -l 15`

Now, I also want to start tmux from my `.bash_profile`, and I am not sure how.

I've read that it's recommended to use `tmux new-session -A -s default` that will attach or create to a new session.

If I do that then the `.tmux.conf` fails with 'no current session'. it want's me to start a new session in the tmux conf.

If I add `new-session -A -s default` to the conf, right before the split command, and then start tmux with `tmux attach` or `rmux attach -t default` or `tmux new-session -A -s default` then it loads, but with some error that it can't find some random .sesssion file, and the split is not exactly how I want it (actually not sure what happens in this case, it says 'restored session').

how exactly should I start tmux in this case?

Comment: i wouldn't include it in the `.bash*` files.  i'd put an alias in `.bash_aliases` or `.bashrc` and execute it manually just after login. (`alias tmxa=' tmux new-session -A -s default'` or whatever.)  this will avoid problems with trying to attach to a session inside your session.

Comment: I still prefer to have it automatically loaded.. What's the difference b\w running it manually and including the command in .bash*?

Answer (score 0):

From some convenient bash environment, either the command line, or ~/.bashrc or bash function or whatever, try the following one-liner:

```
tmux new-session -A -s default \; split-window -v -l 15
```